# HTACCESS redirecting to wrong page

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect

When user enters url `http://localhost/systems/admin` in address bar I need to redirect user to page `http://localhost/systems/admin/login/`

It works fine when enter `/admin`

It does not work properly when I enter `/admin/` (note trailing slashes), it redirects me to some other page `http://localhost/systems/user/login` but I want it to redirect me to same page i.e. `http://localhost/systems/admin/login/`

Below is my entire .htaccess code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /systems/

RewriteRule ^admin$ http://localhost/systems/admin/login/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Why downvote? At least have a courtesy to add a comment..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your .htaccess configuration you are redirecting only `/admin` to `/admin/login/`.

To support a possible trailing slash you should go for something like:

```
RewriteRule ^admin/?$ http://localhost/systems/admin/login/ [R=301,L]
```

Generally speaking I would stick to only one notation (either with or without the trailing slash) and add a rule that always corrects wrong notations (i.e. adding or removing the trailing slash). A rule to remove the trailing slash could be:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

With such a rule you can stick to your original rewrite rule. In this case, however, you should always take care of returning addresses without the trailing slash in order to avoid rewriting when not necessary:

```
RewriteRule ^admin$ http://localhost/systems/admin/login [R=301,L]
```